# Pathauto not updating path portion of new path

Tags: 7, path-aliases

When using the following replacement pattern for all nodes (to get 'hackable' urls that respect the menu hierarchy):

```
[node:menu-link:parents:join-path]/[node:title]
```

I then create a node with title 'Subnode' which is a child of the node 'Parent node'. This will give me a node with the alias /parent-node/subnode. Now when I move the node one level up and change its (menu)title, so that Subnode is now a 'toplevel' node. The [node:title] part gets changed but the [node:menu-link:parents:join-path] not.

The 'Generate automatic URL alias' checkbox is checked.

Now when choose 'Update URL Alias' from the dropdown list in the content pane (/admin/content) the url does get updated properly.

Why doesn't it get updated right away?

Answer (score 0):

I'm running into the same problem, I tried to trace the code and it looks like that token replacement is never called. Not sure if its a bug in token or pathauto module.

Comment: If you have more relevant information regarding whats going wrong codewise we could open a bug. Therefore we would first need to identify the module at fault though.